# Distinct aggregation over multiple columns in Pandas based on column names

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a large Pandas data frame and I want to aggregate the columns differently. I have 24 columns (hours of the day), which I would like to sum, and for all others just take the maximum.

I know that I can write manually the required conditions like this:

```
df_agg = df.groupby('user_id').agg({'hour_0':'sum', 
                                    'hour_1':'sum',
                                    .
                                    .
                                     'hour_24':'sum',
                                    'all other columns': 'max'}
 )
```

but I was wondering whether an elegant solution exists on the lines:

```
df_agg = df.groupby('user_id').agg({'hour_*':'sum', 
                                    'all other columns != hour_*': 'max'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate dictionary by all columns with `hour`, add all another columns to another dictionary, merge them and last pass to `agg`:

```
c1 = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('hour')].tolist()
#also excluded user_id column for avoid `max` aggregation
c2 = df.columns.difference(c1 + ['user_id'])
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961
d = {**dict.fromkeys(c1, 'sum'), **dict.fromkeys(c2, 'max')}

df_agg = df.groupby('user_id').agg(d)
```

Or you can use 2 times `groupby` with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df_agg = pd.concat([df.groupby('user_id')[c1].sum(), 
                    df.groupby('user_id')[c2].max()], axis=1)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Especially the second solution seems brief and very easy to understand at a quick glance. You're amazing as usual! :)